# Process List of Charging Powered Off Device

Tags: adb, root-access, bootloader

Is there any way to access or log the [process list](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ps1.html) when the phone is off, but plugged into my computer charging? I'd like to see what system processes are running when the phone is connected to a power source but is not yet turned on.

My device is rooted, but more importantly my bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: If someone ever makes a device that can run appse when you haven't yet powered it on I'd be impressed.

Comment: @Chenmunka, see answer below

Comment: @Huey it's not in recovery mode. Reproduce steps are literally, 1. turn phone off, 2. plug phone into computer. If you look at the display, it's just showing the charging animation because the phone is off and plugged into a power source.

Comment: @Huey, you might've misinterpreted the question, I was looking for the process list, not a list of all running apps. So I could see what system processes were running when the phone is plugged and only charging - http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ps1.html

Comment: @Huey included a picture of the output to help alleviate any confusion

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, pretty easy actually.
If the bootloader is unlocked and the device is powered off and plugged into your computer, you can just use ADB.

Typing `>adb devices` will result in[image: adb devices output for device charging]

You can then run `adb shell "ps"` and it'll output the process list while in charge mode, like seen below:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that info from? That `recovery` under "List of devices attached" shows up when you're booted into Recovery mode, which means the device is powered-on. This answer is bizarre, though may be true that a very small kernel is running to show that power animation or something! I demand further clarification. And which device are you using? The method doesn't work here on unlocked OnePlus One.

Comment: @Firelord understandable, I also don't know.. Info is completely empirical. I didn't expect it to work so I asked the question, then tried a few things out. Perhaps, since the device is off, ADB is assuming it must be in recovery mode because it wouldn't *expect* an unlocked bootloader. Would have to open the adb code to see what's going on exactly. However I am positive I was not in recovery mode. I literally turned the device off, plugged it in, and used ABD. I would be completely willing to record it as video for the sake of us all.

Comment: @Firelord didn't see your edits before I commented. The bootloader is a kernel that takes care of booting the system, and is what runs when the device is charging but off. I was using a Huawei Y536A1. According to XDA was also possible on LG Ultimate 2 (all that I know, I don't have any more devices to test with).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps those who are well versed with understanding of lower levels of Android like bootloader can provide us some insight.

Comment: @Firelord that's what I'm hoping for, I'll edit my answer to include some of the info from these comments for anyone else who comes here, thanks for asking so I could realize what I wasn't including!:)

Comment: If you really didn't miss something here, that's pretty weird. In order for your local ADB client to *see* the device, the ADB daemon on the device must be active – which requires "something" to be booted. The absolute minimal system active while charging the switched-off device is very unlikely to do that (at least I've never seen such). So could you please answer @Firelord's question and let us know what device this is, and also include what ROM/Android version you use there?

Comment: Could you please provide the link for XDA's thread on LG Ultimate 2 where you saw that thing being possible? Check out browser's history if you don't have it bookmarked or opened in a tab.

Comment: @Izzy absolutely. I did mention this was on the Huawei Y536A1, however android version is 4.4.3. As for rooted ROM, I took it from an XDA post, I will comment the link at a later point tonight when I'm not on the mobile app. In this post http://forum.xda-developers.com/optimus-g-pro/d680-development/boot-charge-lg-pro-lite-d680-developer-t3019859 a user found a bug in the bootloader that allowed him to access it via ADB with a locked bootloader. LG device bootloaders since have had a security upgrade, but it led me to try it on the unlocked Huawei where it also worked.

Comment: @Firelord see above.

Comment: Thanks @chriszumberge! Quoting from [the relevant post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=59127408&postcount=9): *Turns out, LG did a pretty sloppy job, giving me adb access to the device when in offline charging mode […]* This stated by [laufersteppenwolf](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4716493) gives the issue enough weight to make me shut-up with doubts (if he says it is so, I believe him). But also note the context: Wolf considers this misbehaviour/buggy. So it's nothing to count on for other devices, as it's not the way it's expected to work.

Comment: @Izzy, that does make sense. I was under the impression that the "LG ... sloppy job" was what gave laufersteppenwolf access when it *wasn't* bootloader unlocked so he was able to do a lot of not normal things to a locked bootloader device. I'm still trying to prove that this is a functionality available to *any* bootloader unlocked devices (of which I don't have many laying around so it might be awhile)

Comment: @chriszumberge That's what I meant: I fully believe Wolf (he's deep enough into the stuff to know what he's talking about). But I doubt that LG did a sloppy job on Samsung/Motorola/you_name_it ("*any* bootloader unlocked") devices, or that all the resp. manufacturers did the same "sloppy job" as LG with exactly the same consequences ;)